# Constraining time with LINQ

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql, datetime

I'm having difficulty constraining time in a LINQ statement. I am still pretty new with LINQ. The SQL I want to emulate is something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Token, StartTime 
FROM Tokens 
WHERE Token = '050' 
AND StartTime > DATEADD(MI, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This SQL statement gets only rows where the time in the StartTime column is less than 30 minutes from the current time. How would I do this with LINQ? So far my best guess is

```
DateTime cutoff = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
IEnumerable<Tokens> token = dataContext.Tokens.Where(row => row.Token == "050" && 
                                                            row.StartTime > cutoff);
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. Any advise?

Comment: It seems perfectly right to me?! What is not working exactly?

Comment: Possibly the char/string thing as others have mentioned, or maybe a time zone issue, i.e. DateTime.Now returning your local time rather than the local time on the SQL server.

Comment: The token I used is just a simplification of my actual tokens to make the example more readable. I put in a better one. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You may add 30 days to token's StartTime and compare it to current date. You should probably also compare token text as string (double quotes), as it possibly might be a VARCHAR2 type.

```
var token = dataContext.Tokens.Where(r => 
  r.Token == "5" && 
  r.StartTime.AddDays(30).Date >= DateTime.Now.Date
);
```

Edit: probably you want to show last 30 days of operation, to do this date and time should be rounded to date - changed code.

Answer (score 0):

```
row.Token == '5'
```

This jumps out at me. Watch out for using sql's string literal syntax in C#, as it indicates a char - not a string.

Comment: You're right, David. This is just a simplification of my token to make the example more readable. Thanks.